# Integrating OGRE 1.7 in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, ogre3d, ogre

I need to integrate Ogre 3d in Qt 4. I found several codes and suggestions which are unfortunately out-dated. I liked this tutorial

http://irmatden.developpez.com/tutoriels/qt/integration-ogre-qt/

It works with Ogre 1.4.9 (Eihorn) but not with the recent version 1.7.0. Compiling the app with the recent one results in a linker error

```
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x6f6): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::initOgreSystem()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1cfb): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1dde): undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::initialise(bool, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2278): undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::map, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > > const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2c31): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x40): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x10d): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS2_E[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)]+0x47): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1
```

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The memory allocator of your `OgreBuildSettings.h` probably doesn't reflect the one Ogre was actually built with. Change it to the one used when you built Ogre (or just play with the numbers of `#define OGRE_MEMORY_ALLOCATOR`. It happens when you update Ogre and forget to replace `OgreBuildSettings.h` in an alternative include path (maybe your project's).

Answer (score 1):

An Example using QT4 and Ogre Eihort
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/QtOgre

In ogrewidget.cpp just replace....

```
  // setup a renderer
  Ogre::RenderSystemList *renderers = mOgreRoot->getAvailableRenderers();
  assert( !renderers->empty() ); // we need at least one renderer to do anything useful

  Ogre::RenderSystem *renderSystem;
  renderSystem = chooseRenderer( renderers );

  assert( renderSystem ); // user might pass back a null renderer, which would be bad!
```

With....

```
  // setup a renderer
  Ogre::RenderSystemList::const_iterator renderers = mOgreRoot->getAvailableRenderers().begin();
  while(renderers != mOgreRoot->getAvailableRenderers().end())
  {
      Ogre::String rName = (*renderers)->getName();
        if (rName == "OpenGL Rendering Subsystem")
            break;
        renderers++;
  }

  Ogre::RenderSystem *renderSystem = *renderers;
```

And it works with Ogre 1.7.3

To use...

OgreWidget *ogreWidget = new OgreWidget();